# После запуска приложения из службы созданной на C# не отображается иконка приложения в трее

Tags: c#

Добрый день! Создал службу и приложение на C#, служба при запуске запускает приложение. Служба запускается нормально, приложение тоже запускается. Но иконка приложения в трее не появляется, хотя при запуске приложения не из службы - иконка в трее нормально отображается. И служба и приложение - все запускается от имени системы. Если кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой - просьба пролить свет на эту тему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте в свойствах службы поставить галочку "Разрешить взаимодействие с рабочим столом". По умолчанию она снята.

Comment: Я пробовал ставить галочку "Разрешить взаимодействие с рабочим столом", тоже не помогало. Смысл такой, что когда приложение запускается из службы, то она запускается, но его графическая часть не отображается.

Comment: Я знаю, что в Windows 7 запрещено взаимодействие службы напрямую с рабочим столом, но если я это делаю, не из службы, а из приложения - по идее должно работать.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте запускать приложения От имени учетной записи.

Comment: Пробовал и от имени: LocalSystem, User, LocalService и на всякий случай NetworkService. Процесс(приложение) точно запускается, есть в диспетчере задач, а его графического отображения не происходит.

Comment: Проблема в том, что сервис выполняется в отдельной сессии (в диспетчере задач колонка Код сеанса). Когда Вы запускаете приложение, независимо от того, от какой учетки идет выполнение, приложение запускаете в сессии сервиса и, соответственно, не может обращаться к интерфейсу пользовательской сессии. Чтобы это было возможно необходимо само приложение из сервиса запускать в пользовательской сессии. Я не скажу сейчас как это делается, нужно покопаться в параметрах CreateProcess, причем не из C#, а в Win32.